# Custom Dialog filling the screen height

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am trying to create a custom Dialog, and is working just fine, but the Dialog is filling the whole screen height. I've done some unsuccessful research on the internet but I don't have a lot of time for this task, if anyone knows why is this happening I appreciate it hard.

here is the onCreateDialog():

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) builder.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog__warning, mContainer, false);
    txtWarning = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtWarning);
    if(messageWarning.length()>0)
    {
        txtWarning.setText(messageWarning);
    }
    btnOkDialog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOkDialog);
    btnOkDialog.setOnClickListener(MyListener);
    btnCancelDialog = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelDialog);
    btnCancelDialog.setOnClickListener(MyListener);
    builder.setView(view);
    return builder.create();
}
```

and the xml of dialog_warning:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#b1b0b0"
tools:context="ipat.johanbayona.gca.ipat.NewEvidence.Dialog_Warning">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtWarning"
    android:text="Mensaje error" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:id="@+id/btnOkDialog"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:id="@+id/btnCancelDialog"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try doing something like this - `myAlertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);` //Controlling width and height.

Comment: How can i call getWindow from a fragment? can´t manage to get the method

Comment: Try to add the `getWindow().setLayout(600,400);` inside your Dialog Class.

Answer (score 0):

try creating your own theme for the dialog, something like this

```
<style name="AppDialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

and set this theme passing to the dialog's super constructor with R.style.AppDialog

upd. 
it's not the builder's constructor. you should create your own class that extends the AlertDialog, override it's onCreate and the super constructor and your class should be something like this

```
public class YourDialog extends Dialog {

    public YourDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context, R.style.AppDialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dialog__warning);

        txtWarning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWarning);
        if(messageWarning.length()>0)
        {
            txtWarning.setText(messageWarning);
        }
        btnOkDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOkDialog);
        btnOkDialog.setOnClickListener(MyListener);
        btnCancelDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelDialog);
        btnCancelDialog.setOnClickListener(MyListener);
    }
}
```

overriding the main constructor, and passing the  R.style.AppDialog should do the trick. all you need is to call where you want to show the dialog `new YourDialog(context).show();`

note that you don't need to call manually the layout inflater to pass your own contentview, just calling the setContentView with resId will automatically inflate the view beneath.

Comment: I added the style and pass it as a parameter `AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(),R.style.AppDialog);` is there any property I'm missing in the style?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="#b1b0b0"
tools:context="ipat.johanbayona.gca.ipat.NewEvidence.Dialog_Warning">
```

Change "layout_height" to wrap_content. You fixed height and width, that may be the problem depending on your screen size.